# Trying to change UL LI background color jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to change the clicked UL LI link with jquery; it only works with hover event, not with click event. Please see my code below:

```
$("nav ul li").hover(function() {
    $(this).find('a').css('color', '#FF0');
}, function() {
    $(this).find('a').css('color', '#FFF');
});

$("nav ul li").click(function() {
    $(this).find('a').css('color', '#FF0');
    $(this).find('a').siblings().css('color', '#FFF');
});
```

Comment: Sorry I meant change the link color...

Comment: `$(this).find('a').siblings()` probably matches more elements than you'd like to. Can you elaborate on exactly what you want to achieve so we can suggest better solutions? (Posting an example of your markup can also help.)

Comment: Could you post the relevant markup as well?

Comment: Are you sure that your anchor is not sending you to another page ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {                       //run when the DOM is ready
 $(".clickable").click(function() {  //use a class, since your ID gets mangled
  $(this).addClass("active");      //add the class to the clicked element
 });
});
```

Using this method you can simply replace the class with a new set of attributes on click.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, if your anchor is clicked, then you are navigationg to other page, if for some reason you wich to avoid it and do stuff your way, prevent the default navigate action of a anchor click (navigate)

```
$("nav ul li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```